How do I copy a surface deform modifier on an empty hair curve to another hair curve?
new user here! I'm following this tutorial on YouTube and I'm running into some trouble creating the bun using Blender's new hair system.
https://youtu.be/ox6y7KFft70?si=ZeqDakknTdFmhugT
I've created the bun as the tutorial instructs, but when I convert the edge loops into a hair curve, the surface deform modifier doesn't automatically apply like it does when you add an empty hair curve to a random mesh. I was told to copy the modifier on the random mesh to the new bun curve, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that? Unfortunately, I can't really move on with the tutorial until I figure out how to get the surface deform modifier onto the hair curve.
Here's an image for reference:


With the desired objects selected, Shift+Click the curve to make it the active object, then click the arrow to the left of the X on the modifier, and you'll see Copy to Selected.

Ooooh! I had thought Copy to Selected was found by right-clicking the name. That's where I was going wrong. Thank you so much!

Select the target object, shift select the object that has the modifier.
Click "copy to selected" (you can select multiple things at once, as long as the last selection is the one that has the modifier you want to copy)

